# How would I add a background field to my custom WordPress post type using no plugin? I already have my custom WordPress post type working

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I add a background field to my custom WordPress post type using no plugin? I want the field to be able to change the background of the post/image. I already have my custom WordPress post type working. My custom post type is below:

```
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'products',
        // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I would use the Featured Image and then use CSS for the background. You've already added support for it. Would that be good enough for your solution?

Comment: The quickest way is to use something like Advanced Custom Fields.  I realize you said you didn't want a plugin, but you could literally do this in 5 minutes that way.  Otherwise, I would suggest reading up on custom meta fields: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/